# Random number array with lazy initialization

Tags: java, c++, random

For a distributed application project I want to have two instances share the same/know (pseudo-)random numbers.

This can be achieved by using the same seed for the random number generator (RNG). But this only works if both applications use the RNG output in the same order. In my case this is hard or even impossible.

Another way of doing this is would be (psedocode):

```
rng.setSeed(42);
int[] rndArray;
for(...) {
    rndArray[i] = rng.nextInt();
}
```

Now both applications would have the same array of random numbers and my problem would be solved.

BUT the array would have to be large, *very large*. This is where the lazy initialization part comes in: **How can I write a class that where `rndArray.get(i)` is always the same random number (depending on the seed) without generating all values between `0` and `i-1`?**

I am using JAVA or C++, but this problem should be solvable in most programming languages.

Comment: Why can't you control the order in which random numbers are drawn? In the simulation algorithms I have seen that was always defined (and has to! Because otherwise you cannot reproduce results accurately). If you have multiple threads, use a PRNG instance *per thread* and use pre-chosen seeds for all of them.

Comment: How is it possible that your applications can't use the `Random` in the same order but can use array in the same order? Do you really need indexed access (possible with skipping some numbers or possible with multiple access to the same index) or is it just an example?

Comment: Do you want to avoid initializing array _at all_ or just avoid invoking r.n.g. very many times in startup? In the latter case, initialize array with a constant out of r.n.g. range, say -1. Then every thread accesses array in a critical section, and if it gets -1, it initailizes the position with a new generated number.

Comment: The actual application is similar to a game with a random generated map. The map is unlimited (i.e., limited to INT_MAX) but every node sees only a small fraction out of it. Because nodes behave differently, they have different access patterns to the map. - In addition i do not want to save/initialize the map at all. The only thing will be a caching mechanism for already generated cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a formula based on a random seed.

e.g.

```
public static int generate(long seed, int index) {
    Random rand = new Random(seed + index * SOME_PRIME);
    return rand.nextInt();
}
```

This will produce the same value for a given seed and index combination.  Don't expect it to be very fast however.  Another approach is to use a formula like.

```
public static int generate(long seed, int index) {
    double num = seed * 1123529253211.0 + index * 10123457689.0;
    long num2 = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(num);
    return (int) ((num2 >> 42) ^ (num2 >> 21) ^ num2);
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't want linearly-correlated seeds for things like simulations. (Granted, you don't want java.util.Random in that case either ...)

Comment: Your answer seems to be what I am looking for. The java.util.Random version works quite nice. Could you give some explanation why I need the prime number? Should it be a large prime? ... Your second version seems to be similar to what happens within java.util.Random, but slightly different. Why the different magic numbers?

Comment: @masgo You want large primes to avoid any predictable patterns.  The second example may be faster, but uses convoluted mathematical functions i.e. there is no simple way to prove it is properly random.

Answer (score 0):

If it's large **and** sparse you can use a hash table (downside: the numbers you get depend on your access pattern).

Otherwise you could recycle the solution to a problem from the Programming Pearls (search for something like "programming pearls initialize array"), but it wastes memory iirc.

Last solution I can think of, you could use a random generator which can efficiently jump to a specified position - the one at http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1519417 is decently fast, but it generates 16 numbers at a time; anything better?